# Check if a command prints out a string that matches a regexp with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to run:

```
> ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29034) [x86_64-darwin10.4.0]
```

and then see if `1.9.2` is printed out. If so, i return `true`.

How would this method look like using a regexp?

Comment: In what language do you want this check to be made in? Ruby ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using 'RUBY_VERSION', however you could do something like:

```
`ruby --version`.include? "1.9.2"
```

Answer (score 1):

`RUBY_VERSION == "1.9.2"`

Comment: haha awesome..ok if i want to use a regexp match then just out of curiosity? good to know when there is no constant defined.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am off the track here but you do seem to want to check the version from the shell ? Something like this then will do it.

```
export VERSION=`ruby --version | grep 1.9.2`
if [[ -n "$VERSION" ]] ; then
  echo "you have the right version yay!"
else
  echo "bummer dude ><!"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex for this is simply

```
/1.9.2/
```

So

```
s=`ruby --version`
return true if s=~/1\.9\.2/
```

(updated)

Comment: You need to escape the `.`'s otherwise `19992` etc. match too